# How to bind a key sequence to a widget in vi cmd mode zsh?

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, vi-mode

Let's say I want to bind <kbd>R</kbd> to `redo` in vicmd mode.

This works.

```
bindkey -a r redo
```

If I change it to this, it does not work.

```
bindkey -a rr redo
```

I have tried different things with no success. Is this not possible? I know it should be possible to bind sequences to keys in emacs mode, but can you do the same with letters in vi mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard vicmd mode <kbd>R</kbd> is already bound to `vi-replace-chars`.

So when you define <kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to `redo` with

```
bindkey -a rr redo
```

you have two possible actions Zsh could follow when <kbd>R</kbd> is pressed

1. interpret it as the command `vi-replace-chars` or
2. wait for a second character and then interpret the command `redo`

The algorithm for matching keyboard commands in Zsh favors short commands so it will always use the 1. action.

To stop Zsh from doing this you first need to remove the binding for <kbd>R</kbd> with

```
bindkey -a -r r
```

and then add your new option with

```
bindkey -a rr redo
```

You can then also add `vi-replace-chars` with

```
bindkey -a re vi-replace-chars
```

Comment: Ah thank you for that information. Based on what I read, for emacs mode you could have both something like '^x' and '^x^a' and it would wait long enough. Unbinding r fixed the problem; I should have tried that right away. Thank you.